# Flutter correct way to provide a callback function to a stateless widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a stateless widget ( a side panel). When some button on side panel is pressed, it is supposed to call a function which is in its parent stateful widget. This function has an input type String.

My call back function is:

```
    sidePanelTapped(String option){
        switch (option){
          case NEW : {
            if (kDebugMode) print('TappedOption = 1');
            setState(() => tappedOption=1);
          } break;
          case PROGRESS : {
            if (kDebugMode) print('TappedOption = 2');
            setState(() => tappedOption=2);
          } break;
.
.
.
```

My stateless widget has this format:

```
class SidePanel extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function funct;
  final int tappedOption;
  SidePanel({required this.funct, required this.tappedOption});
```

Then in my build section my code is as follows:

```
.
.
.
Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: ()=>funct(optionEntry.key),
                            child: ListTile(
                              minVerticalPadding: 1.0,
                              tileColor: optionEntry.key == NEW
                                  ? tappedOption == 1? Colors.grey[200] 
.
.
.
```

The problem is that my side panel is not changing state as it is suppose to. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

First add a VoidCallback:

```
class SidePanel extends StatelessWidget {
    final Function funct;
    final int tappedOption;
    final VoidCallback onTap;

    SidePanel({
        required this.funct,
        required this.tappedOption,
        required this.onTap,
    });
```

then change:

```
onTap: ()=>funct(optionEntry.key)
```

to

```
onTap: onTap,
```

then pass the function `funct(optionEntry.key)` when calling the `SidePanel`, like this.

```
onTap: () {
    funct(optionEntry.key);
}
```

Comment: what is the advantage of using the voidcallback?  I thought that was used for passing functions callbacks to dependant classes.

Comment: It is better for low coupling. You are less dependent on maintaining the page due to a function execution and keep it free to do what a Stateless was made to do: be a simple view. You will then only need to pass the execution of the function and it is much easier to understand what is happening when you need to change something.